# Inverse of double colon indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in want of figuring out the inverse of double indexing. For example, If I index my data `[::3]` at every three steps, then I want the negation of all those that were selected, so all those not in three steps. How can I achieve this?

For example:

```
df = {
    'OR': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'name': ['EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Arsenal Match Timer Over', 'EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Arsenal Match Timer Over', 'EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Chelsea Match Timer Over', 'Set Time Targeting 15m Next Event 1 Timer Over', 'Set Time Targeting 15m Next Event 1 Timer Over', 'Sportsbook Convert View to Bet Timer Over', 'Timer is up - send back to main profile'],
    'id': ['_unibet-delay_120', '_unibet-delay_120', '_unibet-delay_121', '_unibet-delay_123', '_unibet-delay_123', '_unibet-delay_122', 'unibet-delay_102'],
    'baseOperator': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'operator': ['equals_ignore_case', 'equals_ignore_case', 'equals_ignore_case', 'equals', 'greater_than', 'equals', 'exists'],
    'operand1': ['metrics.5130', 'metrics.29', 'metrics.29', 'metrics.5140', 'metrics.29', 'metrics.5136', 'properties.5012'],
    'operand2': [1, 2, 2, '1', '1', 1, 0]
}
```

Then create a few repeats:

```
DF = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.repeat(x, 3))
```

But how to get the indexing right?

```
DF[::3]

>    OR                                              name                        id baseOperator            operator         operand1 operand2
1    0  EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Arsenal Match Timer Over  _unibet-delay_120         None  equals_ignore_case     metrics.5130        1
2    1  EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Arsenal Match Timer Over  _unibet-delay_120         None  equals_ignore_case       metrics.29        2
3    0  EPL Prekickoff 15m Next Chelsea Match Timer Over  _unibet-delay_121         None  equals_ignore_case       metrics.29        2
20   0    Set Time Targeting 15m Next Event 1 Timer Over  _unibet-delay_123         None              equals     metrics.5140        1
21   1    Set Time Targeting 15m Next Event 1 Timer Over  _unibet-delay_123         None        greater_than       metrics.29        1
22   0         Sportsbook Convert View to Bet Timer Over  _unibet-delay_122         None              equals     metrics.5136        1
23   0           Timer is up - send back to main profile  _unibet-delay_102         None              exists  properties.5012        0
```

Prints out the original dataset, I have tried using `-` signs but this reorders the data.

Comment: One way to think about taking every third row is as a boolean   true  /  false mask that has every third element set to  true, perhaps  with the help of   modulo. Now invert that. Create a mask that is mostly true and has every third element set to false. There, you are done.

Comment: @J_H That is an interesting option, I have not used `mask` before however, both arrays needs to be of the same dimension. I have attempted your approach -- ```fmask = [ x % 3 == 0 for x in range(1,len(df))]
print(df.mask(fmask, inplace=True))``` This only gives ```ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self```

Comment: @J_H I got it working with the following:```fmask = [ not (x % 3 == 0) for x in range(0,len(df))]
print(df.loc[fmask])```